# angular cli proxy not working in latest version

Tags: angular

I'm using the latest angular and angular cli. I made proxy.conf.json that looks like:

```
{

"/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

My server run on port 3000 with this code (just to check):

```
app.get('/api/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello Worfdbfbdld!')
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello Worfdbfbdld!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Then I run it all with:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

In angular I have this ajax call:

```
this.http.get("/api/login").subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Then I get 404. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `*`:

```
"/api/*": {
"target": "http://localhost:3000",
"changeOrigin": true,
"secure": false,
"logLevel": "debug"
 }
```

Comment: tried it also. in both settings the debugger show it works but still 404 and when i navigate manually to the url it works.
[HPM] GET /api/login -> http://localhost:3000

Comment: @PazLazar in console does it show that it made request and request were successful?

Comment: In the debbuger it shows the request.
in console it shows the request goes to http://localhost:4200/api/login

Comment: Ok so server sees the request? And just to verify the version that you are using?

Comment: Can you remove changeOrigin and log level properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154265/discussion-between-alexkhymenko-and-paz-lazar).

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular CLI 1.4 and with this proxy configuration it works fine:

`{ "/api": 
       {  "target": "http://localhost:8000", 

          "secure": false 

       }
}`